# Background Video Width and Height CSS

Tags: html, css, video, background-image, bootstrap-5

I'm making a website with a video on the background. I'm using 80vh (viewport height), but when I press <kbd>f12</kbd>, the video background height went smaller, how to fix it? Should I change it to px or %?

This is my code

HTML:

```
<section class="head-banner">
    <div class="head-background">
        <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="frontend/media/header-background.mp4" type="">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="head-content">
                <h1>FASHION</h1>
                <h1 class="hoks">FESTIVAL</h1>
                <h1 class="hoks">IS HERE</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

SCSS:

```
.head-banner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    .head-background {
        position: relative;
        video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 80vh;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    }

    .head-content {
        position: absolute;
        color: whitesmoke;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 5%;
    }

    h1 {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
        font-size: 72px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .hoks {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `vh` its `viewport height` not vertical, when you press F12 browser open DevTool? what is going to happen?

Comment: Hahaha sorry, i mean Viewport Height. Yess i pressed f12 to open DevTool, and then the height of the video background is shortened, because the Devtool is appears from the bottom of the screen,.

if I don't fix it, will it be a problem on the other device?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a problem, DevTool only for development, user don't need to use it. you can undock in separate window.

Comment: Okay Thanks Mate 